# Why are my map pins getting more inaccurate the further you zoom out? Google maps API V3

Tags: google-maps

http://www.dissentskateshop.co.uk/store-locator/

You can see the map pin sits in the sea, but if you zoom in, it's in the location I set it. I'm pulling my hair out with this one...

Comment: lol.. fun.  You need to show us the code where you set the marker, though.

Comment: I dug through your javascript, couldn't see any reason why.. The only thing that looks odd to me is your custom marker graphic / point creation and I would troubleshoot by removing that first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this behaviour I would guess that the anchor point is not properly set: the anchor seems to be at the bottom left of the image, although the "visible" anchor (the pin) is more right, thus always offset. If you look at the distance in pixels, the offset from the original coordinate is always constant, no matter on what zoom level.

I took a look at your script: in the file `store-locator.js`, method `addMarker`: the fourth parameter of `new google.maps.MarkerImage` is the anchor. You've set it to `(0,32)` (i.e. the bottom left corner of the image). That is wrong! Get the correct anchor location and change the code.

Edit: I've looked at the image: the correct anchor coordinate is (16,31). Give it a try :-)

Comment: Ahh! Such an annoying mistake. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 2):

It is an issue with your custom marker, not a map coordinate registration issue.

You need to put the Anchor point in the center line of the image: 16,32 not 0,32.
I tested this on a copy of your web page.

```
var image    =  new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/intlen_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png',
                                new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
                                new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                                new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
```

Also take care to edit the Shadow image as well.

For fun, I added Greenwich Observatory to your stores.json:

```
{
        "name"      : "Greenwich Observatory",
        "latitude"  : "51.47722",
        "longitude" : "0.0",
        "postcode"  : ""
}
```

At Zoom level 6 (default), the Greenwich Observatory marker is to the east of the Cambridge dot on the map.
Zoom in two levels and it's to the west! That's before fixing the bug of course.

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for your help, both you and Martin were right but I had to accept Martin's response purely because it was first. Thanks :)